# Permisos adecuados a tablas de sistema en SQL Server para ingenieria inversa en java hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, sql-server-2014, ingeniería-inversa

¿A que tablas de SQL server 2014 se les debe dar permisos para que funcione la ingeniería inversa en el framework hibernate de java?
He estado obteniendo este error en eclipse:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: El nombre de objeto 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns' no es válido`

y me di cuenta que es porque el usuario no tiene acceso a las tablas del sistema donde están los metadatos, y por eso es la pregunta. Encontré esta [pagina de sql server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql) donde vienen dichas tablas, pero no sé a que tablas es adecuado darles permisos y a cuales no. ¿Alguien puede indicarme esto, por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulto que aparte de los permisos, hibernate tools tiene un bug [HBX-1646
bug in reading tables with case sensitive collation](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HBX-1646?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:worklog-tabpanel) que reporte. Resulta que si la colación de la base de datos es case sensitive como en `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` la ingeniería inversa fallara antes de ejecutarse tan solo al tratar de leer las tablas de la base de datos de SQL Server (solo ocurre con SQL server). Para corregirlo se debe corregir la clase [SQLServerMetaDataDialect.java](https://github.com/aabrahamhs/hibernate-tools/blob/master/orm/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tool/internal/dialect/SQLServerMetaDataDialect.java) cambiando `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns` por `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, pero como eso lo tiene que hacer la gente de hibernate (aparentemente se resolverá apartir de la versión 6.0.0.Alpha1), la unica forma que encontre de darle la vuelta a este error es usar una colación que no sea case sensitive como en `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.